# What is the actual formula of Average Memory Access time?

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-access

I am confused between the below two formulas. Can anybody help me to clear the confusion regarding the correctness of the formula?

AMAT = hit-time + miss-rate * miss-penalty

and

AMAT = hit-rate * hit-time + miss-rate * miss-penalty

When to use which formula? Are both correct?

Comment: `miss-penalty` in the second equation denotes total miss latency while in the first equation it does denote miss penalty. What sources are you reading from? Are you sure it's called `miss-penalty` in the second equation?

Answer (score 1):

To be accurate, it depends on the design.
Let us consider you have two levels of memory first and second level denoted by **F** and **S** respectively.

Let hit rate is **H** and miss rate is then **1-H**

Avarage memory access time = **H * F  +  (1-H) * (F + S)**  . i, e if it is hit (**H**), then it will be available in the first level **F**. If it is not hit (**1-H**), then it needs to be searched in the next level also **F + S**.

We can solve this into **HF + F - HF + S - HS**

=> **F + S - HS**

=> **F + S (1-H)**

i,e

**first level memmory access time + miss rate * second level memory access time.**

If your design have more than two levels of memory, then the result will depends on those levels as well. But the logic will remain the same.